# Optimizing for ListView and Column?

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a Sentence in flutter docs about performance that says

> Avoid using constructors with a concrete List of children (such as Column() or ListView()) if most of the children are not visible on screen to avoid the build cost.

[link](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/rendering/best-practices)

is there any one who understand what it really means or can explain it with an example?

Comment: for example if your children list has 1000 widgets you most likely see only 10 or so at a time, so better use `ListView.builder` widget that builds only those widgets that are visible (or will be soon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView.builder()` allows us to create children dynamically as the user scrolls, contrary to `ListView` and `Column` that, instead, create all the children in one go.

This optimization gains importance as we deal with long lists of children: we don't need to render items that are not in the view, therefore `ListView.builder()` comes in very handy by creating the widgets on demand.

You can dig into the implementation of the `builder()` constructor of `ListView` in the [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html), or read more about this practice for dealing with long lists in the Flutter [cookbook](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists).

Comment: `ListView.separeted()` also did the same as `ListView.builder()`